# Error when making an unlocked package containing reports

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package

I have been trying to make a package with multiple metadata in it including some reports. After I run the creation command I get an error while verifiying metadata as:

```
Report_Accounts/Accounts_by_Country: columns-field: Invalid value specified: ADDRESS1_STATE_CODE
```

I researched around but I do not seem to find any relatable issue to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for this problem is that your build org is not configured with the required features.

Make sure that you pass the `-f DEFINITIONFILE` argument to [`force:package:version:create`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm#!), with your scratch org definition file. Also make sure that the [`StateAndCountryPicklist`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_stateandcountrypicklist) feature is requested in that scratch org definition.

Comment: Thanks! It has worked. I had forgotten to add `StateAndCountryPicklist` as a feature but I am aware of using definition file to create the package.